# How can i connect a PHP file to a GitHub page (different repositories)?

Tags: php, html, github, github-pages

I have a github page in which there's an "a" tag (). When the user clicks on it i want them to be redirected to a php page, which is in another repository. Which path should i put in "href"?

On local this works

```
<a href="http://localhost/index1.php"
onclick="window.open(this.href); return false">Use the online tool.</a>
```

Comment: GitHub pages are static, so they don't support running/executing `.php` files. If you want to link to the source code of a `.php` file you can find that file in your repository and click the `Raw` link and link to that.

Comment: "Which path should i put in "href"?" — The URL to whatever webserver (not git repository) which supports PHP (so not GitHub Pages) and where you deploy the PHP script to.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub gh-pages will not execute `PHP` code. It only handles static content for now.